# Python can have virtual environments, is there an equivalent for Dart/flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I’m working on several little projects and some of them require different versions of packages and versions of dart flutter. Create virtual environment similar to python?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for virtual environments but then there is an equivalent to nvm: https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm . You can manage your flutter versions using fvm.

Comment: There are no pythonists here, only dartists here. Dartists don't know what it is. You should add the tag python.

Answer (score 5):

you can use tow method

- install different flutter version in multiple path
  [image]

If you're using VSCode, you can download multiple version of flutter SDK into different path and quickly switch between them using Dart&Flutter Plugin

as followin
You need to have two flutter SDK folders. One of them you need to rename it to flutter_beta (or whatever you like, I called it that way because on that one I am always on beta channel and in the original one I am always on stable channel).
Then, inside that flutter_beta folder you need to go to bin folder and rename the flutter file to flutterbeta (or whatever you want)
Then you need to export the path of that new executable like you did to the first one https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path
And that's all, the VSCode settings.json configuration is optional...
[reference1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24236)

---

or

- FVM(flutter version management)
  [image]

In case you have projects in different Flutter SDK versions and do not want to upgrade.

https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6vKde1vIGQ

```
dart pub global activate fvm
fvm
```

and chose the version you will use its sdk

notes:You must add the path to the fvm executable to the $PATH environment variable. After running "pub global activate fvm"
[reference](https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-version-management-a-simple-cli-to-manage-flutter-sdk-versions/)

Answer (score 1):

This package can help you to have multiple Flutter environments on one machine and change them depending on the project you're working on (Like python virtual environments).

https://github.com/lukeurban/flenv

Answer (score 0):

When you a start a Flutter project it runs it's own "Virtual machine" for debugging during Development. [Check Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq)
[Check Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend [fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation) instead of setting up extra alternate versions of flutter sdk for each project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31385211)